# PyGObject, hex color to Gdk.RGBA

Tags: pygobject

i found this code

```
gdk_rgba_parse ()
```

which should allow me to do something like

```
Gdk.RGBA.parse(#7F7F7F)
```

Error:

```
 TypeError: unbound method parse() must be called with RGBA instance as first argument   (got str instance instead)
```

using the RGBA color ( in percent, from 0 to 1 )

Docs:

https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-RGBA-Colors.html#gdk-rgba-parse
http://www.crategus.com/books/cl-cffi-gtk/pages/gdk_fun_gdk-rgba-parse.html

But I'm kinda lost, i struggle to translate from C to PyGOBject and understanding the arguments of the function.. any help would be appreciated!

---

Since i didn't find the right solution, i made this converter:

```
def hex_to_rgba(value):
    value = value.lstrip('#')
    if len(value) == 3:
        value = ''.join([v*2 for v in list(value)])
    (r1,g1,b1,a1)=tuple(int(value[i:i+2], 16) for i in range(0, 6, 2))+(1,) 
    (r1,g1,b1,a1)=(r1/255.00000,g1/255.00000,b1/255.00000,a1)

    return (r1,g1,b1,a1)
```

It works..

Comment: It is something like (color:=Gdk.RGBA()).parse('#7F7F7F')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function requires an instance of a GdkRGBA struct:

```c
gboolean
gdk_rgba_parse (GdkRGBA *rgba,
                const gchar *spec);
```

This translates to Python as a method on a Gdk.RGBA instance which mutates the structs contents:

```python
color = Gdk.RGBA()
color.parse('#7F7F7F')
color.to_string()  # 'rgb(127,127,127)'
```

It's not a very nice API for Python but every once in a while you have to deal with these kind of things with introspection based bindings. lazka's docs should be more helpful than the C ones:

http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gdk-3.0/structs/RGBA.html#Gdk.RGBA.parse